# Share element adapter to Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to share element from `RecycleView` `Adapter` to `Activity` but I got this error:

> incompatible types: `Context` cannot be converted to `Activity`

```
        holder.img_pro.setTransitionName(context.getString(R.string.share));

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Details_activity.class);
        Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create(holder.img_pro, holder.img_pro.getTransitionName());
        i.putExtra(AppConstants.SCREEN, "0");

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, pair1);
        context.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: not every context is an Activity. On which line do you get this error?

Comment: ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, pair1);

Comment: then you have to pass an `Activity` as a first parameter, not a context. If you are sure that your `Context` is an `Activity`, then just cast it to `Activity`

Comment: I also try this (Activity)context ,here an adapter call from fragment

Comment: please show your adapter file.

Comment: `I also try this` and what was the result? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` first parameter accepts `Activity` and you are passing `Context` try to cast your `Context` to `Activity` or pass the `Activity` to your click handling which I hope its outside the `ViewHolder`